# Apache VirtualHosts not working/redirecting? (Reverse proxy)

Tags: apache-2.4, reverse-proxy, virtualhost, apache2

I am trying to set up Apache as a reverse proxy on a new Ubuntu 22.04 virtual machine. We have an existing Apache reverse proxy on Ubuntu 18.04 where everything is working as intended. This new reverse proxy is supposed to replace our older one, but the virtual hosts don't seem to be working correctly.

I have done the following:

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-get install apache2
a2enmod proxy
a2enmod proxy_http
a2enmod proxy_balancer
a2enmod lbmethod_byrequests
```

I disabled the default page in sites-enabled.

```
a2dissite 000-default.conf
```

I then created a new virtual host and enabled it.

```
vi 001-trupage.azmedien.ch.conf
a2ensite 001-trupage.azmedien.ch.conf
```

It looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost trupage.azmedien.ch:80>
    ServerName trupage.azmedien.ch
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://10.200.0.130/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://10.200.0.130/
</VirtualHost>
```

I then restarted & reloaded the Apache.

```
systemctl restart apache2
systemctl reload apache2
```

I created a host file entry on my Windows PC to test if this very basic configuration works, it points to my Apache server.

When I then try to reach trupage.azmedien.ch it leads me to the Apache default website instead of actually redirecting me to the correct server (which is defined with ProxyPass in the virtual host).

It seems like it doesn't recognize the virtualhost for some reason? When I replace "trupage.azmedien.ch:80" with "*:80" and then open it in my browser the ProxyPass works. But obviously, that is not what I want as there will be multiple virtual hosts.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName trupage.azmedien.ch
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://10.200.0.130/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://10.200.0.130/
</VirtualHost>
```

Here is the output from `apache2ctl -S`, 213.146.11.131 is the IP of the old reverse proxy, but I have no clue where it's coming from or why it's showing up here:

```
root@azprox10:~# apache2ctl -S
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified doma                                                                                                                               in name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress th                                                                                                                      is message
VirtualHost configuration:
213.146.11.131:80      is a NameVirtualHost
         default server localhost (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/001-trupage.azmedi                                                                                                                               
         en.ch.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost localhost (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/001-trupage.azm                                                                                                                               
         edien.ch.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost opvsg.chmedia.ch (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/002-opvs                                                                                                                               
         g.chmedia.ch.conf:1)
ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www/html"
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
Mutex proxy: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="/var/lock/apache2" mechanism=fcntl
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="www-data" id=33
Group: name="www-data" id=33
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the dns name in the `<VirtualHost>` line. `<VirtualHost *:80>` is fine, you can have multiple of those, relevant is the `ServerName` directive.

The entry in the `<VirtualHost>` line only defines on which interface Apache should listen. If you enter a hostname here, Apache tries to resolve it to an IP address to find the correct interface.